# Why are there so many feature-request with no official response?

Tags: discussion

There are lots of questions tagged [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) that don't have a [`status-*`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/status~) response.

How do we interpret this?
Is it because they are declined by default?
We just have to wait for a response (the team is very busy)? Is Jeff the only one that reviews this questions?

I suppose the ones that have negative votes may (or may not) be declined by default, but there are quite a few with some to a lot upvotes that should have an official answer.

Comment: The `feature-requests` tag in this question is intended

Comment: Take your pick: Because Jeff is too lazy to respond. Because Jeff is too busy to respond. Because Jeff thinks your requests are stupid. Because Jeff is too busy thinking other requests are stupid to look at yours. Because Jeff is too lazy because he's spent too much time busily looking at stupid requests like yours. Because Jeff is too busily stupid your lazy spent much requests looking too thinking other yours respond because Jeff.

Comment: @urd, I'm not just talking about mine, but your point is taken

Comment: I've asked the same question on meta.se (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3193/can-we-get-an-acknowledgement-on-feature-requests), I guess it is partly down to the sheer weight of numbers

Comment: @rich, be advised, SO is not SE (including the development team and general practices)

Comment: @Downvoter, I'm aware of that, but many of the same principles apply. Apparently including not responding to all the feature requests that quickly

Comment: @urdnot: i think that covers all the possibilities right there.  especially the descent into inanity and incomprehensibility there at the end.

Comment: Woah, wait a minute - I realize that SO and all of it's components are Jeff's baby - but the responsibility to answer/look at all of them by himself is overwhelming! This does not seem like a good business practice at all - I thought he had a team to help him with this. If he doesn't he **should**.

Comment: see also: [Why don't we get responses from bug reports?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186803/why-dont-we-get-responses-from-bug-reports)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I work in another publicly accessible community, where bug reports and feature requests are happily solicited from the userbase.

We have *thousands* of open idea requests (the codebase is nearing 20 years old), and close only a sizeable fraction of those opened regularly.

From our perspective, the idea requests are welcome, but not all of them are actionable; some are brilliant, and are implemented immediately because they work well with our vision; some are entirely incompatible and are closed/denied.

The majority fit in between; they're ideas that would work with a bit of tweaking, or a bit of thought, but aren't necessarily on the primary development roadmap, so don't get our attention immediately. Nor do they warrant closing, because they are relevant, merely not timely or important.

Because our developers have their own ideas, their own neverending todo lists, we treat the open idea pile more as inspiration than as a roadmap. There's very much a feeling of "we'll get to it when we've run out of other things to do", but this never happens in practice.

Not to speak for Jeff and the others, but I think it's a normal thing to have to choose between two equally bad things in a public forum like this: either responding to most feature requests with a "denied", and so risk upsetting the folk who love the community enough to contribute with their own ideas; or leave some of them dangling because they're not immediately and obviously wrong, but to do something worthwhile with them takes more time and effort than the idea deserves *right now*.

Comment: They have a status-deferred status, which I guess wil fit in here. It's not yet decided what to do with it, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Ikke: IMHO [status-deferred] here would mean "we are going to implement this - not right now, but in the future". It has a feeling of *approval* to it - something which may not be warranted in most cases: there's approval, disapproval, and indifference.

Answer (score 8):

As Jeremy notes it is, sadly, kind of a lose-lose proposition to follow up on every single feature req.

As always,**please vote up feature requests you agree with**! I assure you that I regularly look at the highest voted bugs and feature requests which are not tagged with a [status-*]. Anything with a lot of votes is much more likely to be acted upon... So convince you fellow meta users that your request has merit, first!

Comment: I wonder what happens if this question gets to the top of that list...?

Comment: The universe explodes

Comment: A feature request stack overflow?

Comment: @Antony, this question is not a feature-request

Comment: @downvoter - phew, that was close

Comment: I assume, paying 5c/upvote to captcha-solvers from China wouldn't be so welcome?