# How long is a normal time for a feature request to be approved or denied?

Tags: discussion, meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are there so many feature-request with no official response?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40434/why-are-there-so-many-feature-request-with-no-official-response)

There are some feature requests like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45200/add-warning-when-changing-display-name) that have been asked two years ago, but are still unanswered. Are Stack Exchange team aware of such old forgotten requests? How long is considered normal for a feature request to be approved or denied?

Comment: *[6 to 8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/176080)* ;-)

Comment: Meta Meta Stack Overflow? :)

Comment: see also: [Why don't we get responses from bug reports?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186803/why-dont-we-get-responses-from-bug-reports)

Answer (score 8):

**What you'll be told:**

> [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514)

**The actual amount of time:**

That varies.  Depending on a feature request, it's something that could be very easy (like say, fix pluralization bugs, or maybe not) or very difficult, like say putting completely new subsystems in.

And that's assuming the feature request is even being considered.  Not *every* feature request has merit, and even of the many that *do*, sometimes the work that is going to be put into implementing a feature on the site isn't doesn't justify the work behind that feature.

Stack Exchange is a company like any other: they have many things that they have to prioritize; one feature request has to be balanced against time, money, resources (people) other feature requests (of which there can be hundreds, if not thousands), bugs, new features, maintenance, etc.

In other words, I wouldn't expect a hard number on it.  The best you could do for a feature request is to hope that it will be tagged [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) which indicates that it's been prioritized by the staff and that it will *eventually* come (if not already being worked on).

If you really want to increase the likelihood that a proposed feature request is considered by one of the members of the Stack Exchange team, you should [start a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) on that question.

Comment: As an aside: I think most feature requests go to status-completed without first being (publicly) tagged status-planned?

Comment: @Arjan Possibly?  Given that cycles *seem* to be relatively short, it wouldn't seem worth the overhead to mark things `status-planned` and then `status-completed` after deployment.